# Check for model "dirtiness"

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Is there any convenient way to perform a check about whether my application `model` has been changed by the user? I need it in order to indicate the user about unsaved changes.

It is worth mentioning that I'm using no forms in my app and that my `model` is trickles down to children components from the root component of the app which in turns means that it's might be mutated down there as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up performing deep objects comparison in order to test for modification on the bound model by cloning the initial pristine model's object and compare it against its counterpart updated object right before leaving the page.

Few points:

- I used the following package for the comparison: [deep-equal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal)
- I made this compare on the `window.onbeforeunload` event

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look at ngModelChange, and change detection in general in Angular.

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/forms/index/FormControl-class.html

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html

Since the $digest mechanism is now "Zones" as well (onTurnDone), knowing something about them is powerful.

http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/01/zones-in-angular-2.html